# Solr query if value matches one of several intervals

Tags: solr, range

I'm looking for a way to build "inverse" range queries, i.e instead of defining a field

```
<field name="myfield" type="int" ...>
```

and then specifying an interval in a query

```
myfield:[x TO y]
```

I rather want to define the an "interval field" in my schema

```
<field name="myfield" type="<whatever_fits_here>" multivalued="true" ...>
```

so that this field's values might be, for instance,

```
[100 TO 250], [460 TO 800], [970 TO 1040]
```

A query will then contain an exact value of this field, so that a record will match if the value is contained in any of its intervals.

Note: Collecting all possible values from the intervals into a multi-valued field is not an option here, this would result in about 10000 values per record in many cases (i.e. the upper and lower bounds of the intervals differ by that number).

Comment: How to define a field that will allow me to achieve this? Or, if there is no appropriate field type: How can I attach intervals to a record so that querying in the way I described will work?

Answer (score 3):

Poly fields as [described in this blog post](http://lucene.grantingersoll.com/2009/12/24/complex-fields-aka-poly-fields-in-apache-solr/) must be what you are looking for.

It includes the schema definition for a `location(Double,Double)` type:

```
<fieldType name=”location” class=”solr.PointType” dimension=”2″ subFieldType=”double”/>
<field name=”store” type=”location” indexed=”true” stored=”true”/>
```

And a query:

```
q=store:[44,-90 TO 46,-94]
```

---

So you can create a range(Int,Int) field type and a multivalued field that uses it.

```
q=myfield:[75,* TO *,75] //a range that includes 75
q=myfield:[50,* TO *,100] //a range that includes 50-100
```

**Disclaimer:** I never used poly fields myself. I dont know how those queries work on a multivalued field.

Comment: Thanks. Certainly looks very interesting, though it may still not be what I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do that on an [UpdateProcessor](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor&ei=sMSXT4L3NMaFhQfcvuyWBg&usg=AFQjCNGW_wkeNXMoi7KWBwmC4HryYf9ddw&sig2=2enE87DcPUDdoien3g7e1g), you can look into the value of that field, and set another field2 to 'range1', 'range2' etc depending on where it belongs, then you query field2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm aiming at. My question is what the field's contents must look like in order to be queryable in the way I described.

Comment: then I still don't totally understand the question, how would your queries look like?

Comment: Based on my examples above, a query would be e.g. `myfield:980`. Then a record that has e.g. [800 TO 1200] as the value for myfield would match, since 980 lies inside this interval.